# iCloud synchronization on tvOS

Tags: ios, icloud, tvos

has anybody managed to get iCloud working on tvOS so far?

I am using key-value-storage and it successfully saves everything in iCloud. However, it does not synchronize the data between the iOS-App and the tvOS-App. I am using the same bundle-identifier for both apps.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

So, it appears that Apple may have an issue here on the tvOS side, because if I follow Apple's instructions on **Configuring Common Key-Value Storage for Multiple Apps** **I can share between and iOS App and a macOS App, but not the tvOS app** using exactly the same setup.

Below are my results:

Apple's Instuctions that I used 1st:
[image: Apple Instructions]

So, CloudKit is all about the default **Container** rather than the App bundle ID directly.  So, I setup my Primary iOS app with default container that will become the key-value share container.

[image: Shared Container]

*Here is my Primary Entitlements file:*
[image: Primary Entitlements]
I then stored two NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore pairs in the default store and retrieved the values:

```
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().dictionaryRepresentation
```

[image]

So, in my macOS app I enable CloudKit as well, and remove the default container and set it to the Primary iOS apps container.  Then in the *Entitlements* file I manually setup the `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier` to include the Primary App's bundle ID:

Uncheck default container and toggle Primaries:
[image: Secondary Container]

*Here is my Secondary macOS Entitlements file:*
[image: Secondary Entitlements]

**Then I run the macOS app and presto**, I have the key-value pairs from the primaries default key-value store and retrieved the values easy-peasy:

```
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().dictionaryRepresentation
```

[image: Secondary Entitle]
If I then make the **SAME EXACT MODIFICATIONS** to my tvOS app, the defaultStore() show as empty and I cannot get it to share with the iOS and macOS app.

*Here is my Secondary tsOS Entitlements file:*
[image: tsOS Entitlements]

And no presto, **no values**:
[image: tsOS no share]

Comment: Update: I took the same exact configurations as above, but switched it so that the tvOS app was the primary and it worked fine and I share the same key-value pairs.   I will re-post if I can figure out what causes one to work and not the other.