# iCloud: Sync key-value-storage between iOS and tvOS

Tags: ios, icloud, tvos, apple-tv, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I have an app running on iOS and tvOS. I've set up settings sync using iCloud key-value storage:

- iOS version synchronizes data using iCloud KVS. This working fine.
- tvOS version synchronizes data using iCloud KVS. Also working fine.
- However, I cannot get **the iOS and tvOS versions to synchronize with each other**.

I believe I have followed all the steps correctly:

- Same app id, same bundle id.
- Same iCloud account logged in on all devices.
- The field `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier` in the entitlements is identical ($(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)).
- Key name is identical
- Both apps are syncing over the network (it's not just local cache).

Has anyone gotten cross-iOS/tvOS synchronization working? Is this even possible? Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering here for posterity: cross-sync was actually working correctly and the mistake was actually in how we handled serializing and deserializing of the value stored. We missed the exception until we looked deeper.

Answer (score 2):

I think Apple has a problem here, because I can share between and iOS App and macOS App no problem, but when I apply the same procedures and entitlements to my tvOS App I cannot retrieve the shared key-values.   I just responded to a similar question and the full results of my testing can be found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36778154/6145996

Above, you mention that you set the `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier`, but CloudKit is all about the default Container as well.  You need to make sure that your app is using your primary shared container as well.  Here are Apple's instructions:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Dan, thanks for taking the time to look into this. Unfortunately, it looks like it was an issue in our xml serialization code (the value we were serializing was an xml string). We actually got the tvOS version to sync correctly in the end.

Comment: Just want to add that I don't use CloudKit at all so the default container issue doesn't affect it.